# Using ruby 2.1.2 instead of OS X system ruby by default

Tags: ruby, macos, bash

I'm creating lots of small programs, I'm having trouble with gems not running and being screwy because each of my new projects created is using my system ruby instead of ruby 2.1.2 which is on my computer.

Every time I make a new project I have to navigate to the root file in my console and type

```
source ~/.bash-profile
chruby ruby-2.1.2
```

What does that code do? and how can I automatically use ruby 2.1.2 instead of my system ruby?

Comment: Do you ever need older Ruby? If you only want the newest one, then why not uninstall the old ones and reinstall Ruby?

Comment: I was told that I cannot uninstall the ruby that comes with mac

Comment: Don't remove your system ruby! There are os packages that depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

I just put a `.ruby-version` file in my home directory.

`echo 2.1.2 > ~/.ruby-version`

Chruby looks up your directories until it find one or it uses the system ruby.  If you're in a login shell, you should need to source your bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

step 1
`source ~/.bash_profile`

step 2
`which ruby`

step 3 - use the output of which ruby and in your ~/.bash_profile 
`PATH="/path/to/my/ruby2.1.2/ruby:${PATH}"
export PATH`

Comment: I don't quite understand what this is or what it does

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't actually make any sense.

Comment: it is to set the path of you ruby installation in your bash_profile.  it is going to your system ruby installation because the path to your ruby is not set or is getting overwritten.  to have your ruby installed binary executed put it before the system installed ruby.

Answer (score 0):

chruby is just one of many Ruby version managers. [The instructions say that you can set up a default ruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#default-ruby) like so:

```
If you wish to set a default Ruby, simply call chruby in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zprofile:

chruby ruby-1.9
```